# Execution time of a mysql query, slow in php than phpmyadmin . How I can overcome this

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was running a query in phpmyadmin, it takes around 0.0012 sec to execute.

```
 Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 727,934 total, Query took 0.0012 sec)
```

may be because of by default limitation in phpmyadmin. But it count the total no of row.

But in php, I need the total no of row .I was running the query without limitation that takes around 6-8 second of time to execute the query.

is their any way to solve this issue.

Comment: Actually creating a counter variable and save it to another table or file might be the way to go with that number of rows. Depending on the business value of that count you could update it more frequently or less frequently.

Comment: if you want just the total, execute `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;`. Otherwise, it depends on your database interface. MySQL does have a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` operator that lets you use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

Comment: Additionally, you should specify a clearer title for the question. What is that you *exactly* want? The rows? Some rows and the count? The count only? **And** you should supply some information about your setup. What do you use to query MySQL? PDO? mysqli? The deprecated mysql_* functions? Other? -- as they say, *help us help you*.

Comment: i am using    " **select count(*) where c.taxon_ID=695850  
and gi.gene_id=c.gene_id
and gi.gene_id = g.gene_id
and nf.na_feature_id=gi.na_feature_id** " query.When i am running in terminal it takes around 6 second time.but in phpmyadmin when I am running the **same query without count** it takes around 0.0012 sec time

Comment: How fast does your query run when using this? `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'`

Comment: What function are you using to run the query? And how long does the query *with count* - *exactly* the same query - take in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: BTW, a useful information to include in the question would be the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c
 JOIN gi ON (c.gene_id = gi.gene_id)
 JOIN nf USING (gi.gene_id = nf.na_feature_id)
 JOIN g  USING (gi.gene_id = g.gene_id)
 WHERE c.taxon_ID = 695850;
`

Comment: I am sorry about the I missed the table name while writing the name.the query is **select count(*) from PROP c,gene g,geneinstance gi,nafeatureimp nf where c.taxon_ID=695850 and gi.gene_id=c.gene_id and gi.gene_id = g.gene_id and nf.na_feature_id=gi.na_feature_id**   this query takes around 6 second time.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and in my case it was due to the fact that I was not using the correct data types. So while I wanted to query my `VarChar` Type Index Field with a VarChar I mistakenly formulated the query in such a way that I queried it with and Int Paramter. This resulted in the index not being utilized but rather a full table scan being performed. By example I did:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Indexfield = 015523;
```

when I should have done the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Indexfield = '015523';
```

There is some more insight into the issue here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/08/why-index-could-refuse-to-work/